# Proof for $ \vdash Q \rightarrow (P \rightarrow Q) $ in symbolic logic.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I need help about proving the following sequent:

$$ \vdash Q \rightarrow (P \rightarrow Q) $$

I tried to prove it by trying to introduce a conditional proof, but somehow can't get the suppositions correctly in the beginning. I would appreciate some help.

Additionally, here is another similar sequent I've supposedly proved, but not completely sure:

$$ \vdash Q \rightarrow (P \rightarrow P) $$

[image: Stackoverflow doesn't let me insert a picture yet, so this is a link to the proof.]

**Explanations for the proof:**

CP: Conditional Proof Introduction

A: Assumption

Leftmost Column: Score-board for keeping track of suppositions.

I'd appreciate any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

1. $Q$ (Assumption)
2. --- $P$ (Assumption)
3. --- --- $Q$ (Restating 1)
4. --- $P \rightarrow Q$ (Conditional proof discharging assumption 2)
5. $Q \rightarrow (P \rightarrow Q)$ (Conditional proof discharging assumption 1)

The tricky bit here is understanding what role line 3 plays: we need to restate the first assumption to make it the conclusion of the second inner proof which starts by assuming $P$.

Answer (score 2):

The conditional proofs are rather similar.  For the second you have.

- Suppose $Q$.  Suppose $P$.  Reiterate $P$.   Discharge the assumptions.

[Well, the reiteration is redundant, but shows how they are similar.]

$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\begin{array}{l}\begin{array}{l}\text{The above}\\\fitch{}{\fitch{~~1.~Q}{\fitch{~~2.~P}{~~3.~P}\\~~4.~P\to P}\\~~5.~Q\to(P\to P)}\end{array}&&\begin{array}{l}\text{What you had (also valid)}\\\fitch{}{\fitch{~~1.~Q}{\fitch{~~2.~P}{~}\\~~3.~P\to P}\\~~4.~Q\to(P\to P)}\end{array}\end{array}$$

Just do the same for the first proof.

- Suppose $Q$.  Suppose $P$.  Reiterate $Q$.   Discharge the assumptions.

---

**tl;dr** Basically what you need is the rule of reiteration.  If something was derivable under a subset of the current assumptions, you may inference it.

In your system, anything derived (or assumed) under assumptions (1) or (2) may be inferenced to hold under (1)(2).

Answer (score 0):

Here are both proofs providing results similar to the other answers but in a [Fitch-style proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/):

[image]

Line 3 using reiteration (R) repeating line 1.

[image]

Note that line 2 is both the antecedent and consequent of the conditional represented as a subproof with only one line 2-2.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/